# MATLAB script that can call .mat files without directory

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB script and a lot of folders that are called in that script. I am sending out the script, which is part of a publication and would like to make the script freely accessible along with the .mat files. I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this where the user can just run the script and the files can be called from the script. So it's like a software that just calls the .mat files rather than a code that the user needs to read and understand to call the files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

1. Determine the directory dynamically and use that to load the .mat files (preferred)

   ```
   thisdir = fileparts(mfilename('fullpath'));
   matpath = fullfile(thisdir, 'subdirectory', 'file.mat');

   data = load(matpath);
   ```
2. Put the folder containing the .mat files on the PATH and then load them with just the name

   ```
   addpath('/folder/containing/mat/files')

   data = load('file.mat');
   ```
3. Have the user select the files using `uigetfile`

   ```
   [fname, pname] = uigetfile();
   filename = fullfile(pname, fname);

   data = load(filename);
   ```

Comment: Also [`genpath`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genpath.html) might be useful.